# Quick question on If(!x()) where x() is a function

Tags: c, if-statement

Guys, I am not exactly sure what happens here for the if statement. I did a bunch of google searches, but nothing comes up. Obviously, the function x() returns something. Either a 1 or a 0. But I am not sure what it does. Is it short hand for x() == 0 or x() == 1. I am just going over coding examples and I noticed it.

Comment: `If(!x())` calls function `If`, passing it as argument `!x()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(!x())
{
   // executes if x() is 0
   // x() == 0
}
```

```
if(x())
{
   // executes if x() is non-0
   // x() != 0
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is short hand for `if(x()==0){ // stuff }`

Note that `x()` does not have to return only '0' or '1'.  In C, any non-zero value is considered TRUE in a conditional statement and the negation of any non-zero value is ZERO.

Answer (score 0):

`if(!x())` just checks if `x()` returns something that evaluates to false, in other words `if(x() == false)` or `if(x() == 0)` is the same.

Answer (score 0):

That means `x() == 0`. And `if (x())` means `if (x()!=0)`

Answer (score 0):

In C, 0 is considered false and all other numbers are considered true. In you if-statement, you are saying "if `x()` is not true" which is equivalent to "if `x()` is false". Therefore, `if(!x())` is the same thing as `if(x()==0)`.